# Display weekday from UIDatePicker in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to display selected date from UIDatePicker following format .How is this possible? Please help me
Format is : `Sat Feb 23 3:42 PM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for your desire output:

```
NSDate *chosen = [datePicker date];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm a"];

NSString *formated_date  = [formatter stringFromDate:chosen];

NSLog(@"formated date is : %@", formated_date];
```

You can change the format of the date by reading this link:
http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 1):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ;   
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:yourPickerDate];
 NSInteger yourWeekDay = [components weekday];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFomatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormat:@"DDD MMM dd mm:ss aa"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it....

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm aa"];

NSLog(@"format is : %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date]);